# How to center the current line to 80% height of the current window, in NeoVim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

As title. Since no one wants to become a turtle, I want to setup a behavior like `M` but instead pin the current line to 80% height (0% start from bottom) of the current window, not to center.

Comment: M doesn’t center lines; it goes to the middle line. Do you perhaps mean zz, zt, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

`:h H` accepts a count, so you can do something like this:

```
exe "normal " .. winheight(0) * 80 / 100 .. "H"
```

which translates to `XH` where `X` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Since I don't like scrolloff, I update to this new version:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'M', '<cmd>lua pin_to_80_percent_height()<CR>', NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
function _G.pin_to_80_percent_height()
  vim.opt.scrolloff = 5
  vim.cmd("exe 'normal! zt'")
  vim.opt.scrolloff = 0
end
```

---

### old answer

1. Set `scrolloff` to `5`

   ```
   vim.opt.scrolloff = 5
   ```
2. Set keymap `M` to `zt`.

   ```
   vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'M', 'zt', NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
   ```